# Automatically make matplotlib axes square and equal xlim and ylim

Tags: python, matplotlib

Let's say that I want to plot an ellipse in matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =   np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100))
y = 2*np.cos(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100))

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The result looks like a circle:
[image]

I can get the result that I want by adding five lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =   np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100))
y = 2*np.cos(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100))

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)

#make the axes square and equal
ax.set_aspect('equal')

minimum = np.min((ax.get_xlim(),ax.get_ylim()))
maximum = np.max((ax.get_xlim(),ax.get_ylim()))

ax.set_xlim(minimum*1.2,maximum*1.2)
ax.set_ylim(minimum*1.2,maximum*1.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But this seems very clunky. Is there a function built into matplotlib to give the expected behavior automagically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google threw this up: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/equal_aspect_ratio.html.
I haven't tested it myself, though.

```
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
ax.margins(0.1)
```

Comment: Change "axes()" to "ax". Then I'll accept this answer

Comment: this doesn't equalize x- and y-lims.

Answer (score 0):

If it is of any use, here is the similar code for **MATLAB**:

```
% Make axes equal in size and lenght
% ax3 is an axe() object.
    axis (ax3,'auto')
    axis (ax3,'square')
    minimum = min(abs([ax3.XLim,ax3.YLim]));
    maximum = max(abs([ax3.XLim,ax3.YLim]));
    limit = max(minimum,maximum);
    limit = round(limit,0);
    axis(ax3,[-limit limit -limit limit]);

    ticks = [-limit:limit/5:limit];
    xticks(ax3, ticks);
    yticks(ax3,ticks);
    grid(ax3,'on')
```